# Stop the Service after the Vibrating the Phone in android?

Tags: android, service

I am trying to learn service in android.My goal is like that i will pass a LatLng Object to the service then service will do something with that and when the work will be finished then it will buzz the phone for sometime and stop.Finally the service will be finished.Now I have some query on that:

> I will call the service from my app and user can close my app though
>   service is not finished.will service do the job initiated by my app or
>   it will also finish??

What i studied take me here that service will continue to execute and one thing i don't have to return anything back to activity who has initiated the service.I have written some code.Can anyone help me out??

```
public class MapService extends Service {


    private boolean isRunning  = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");

        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

        //Creating new thread for my service
        //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                   //here i will do my work



                    if(isRunning){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Service running");
                    }
                }

                //Stop service once it finishes its task
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        isRunning = false;

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }
    }
```

Will it work if user closes the app??

Answer (score 0):

Yes this service will run even if user will close app.It is also possible if android system demands memory service will be stopped but it will restart again
as you have set your flag START_STICKY in your **onStartCommand**.

Answer (score 0):

On Android KitKat and above(4.4+), the service will be stopped if user **swipe** kills the application and it **won't** be restarted by the system.  See this discussion([1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/H-DSQ4-tiac)). If the application was stopped by Android system itself (for low resources), the service will be restarted after a while(use `START_STICKY` flag).

On Android 4.3 and below, service will be restarted irrespective of whether application was stopped by system or user(use `START_STICKY` flag).

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```